# ExFat USB-mount not updated in Docker container

Tags: linux, usb, mount, docker

I want to let a docker container access data from a mounted USB external hard drive (ExFat). I mounted the hard drive to an existing and empty `/tmp/driveTest` folder.

Next, I mounted the `tmp` folder into the docker-container by entering `- '/tmp:/mnt/fs'` in my docker-compose.yml file. When the Docker container starts, it successfully reads the data from the hard drive. But when I unmount the drive, without restarting the Docker container, the docker container still sees the folder/file structure while it should not.

When I start the Docker container and mount the drive then, it does not see the folder/file structure at all while it should.

I have tried the options with the `privileged: true` flag, but that does not seem to have any effect. I also unsuccessfully tried a different mount option:

```
- type: bind
  source: /tmp
  target: /mnt/fs
```

If it is possible what I want to achieve, then how?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution, after a lot of trial-error.

In the `docker-compose.yml` file, I have created a named volume like this:

```
volumes:
 usb-drive:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bind
      device: /home/user/usb-mount/
```

Then, for the container service settings:

```
    volumes:
      - usb-drive:/mnt/usb
```

This volume gets updated when you perform `mount` and `umount` actions to the `/home/user/usb-mount/` folder.

EDIT: Just make sure you mount the USB-drive(s) after the volume has been created. The path of the mount point is different than `/home/user/usb-mount/` after the volume has been created by docker-compose.